# Dataload the Default Account Team box of "Automatically add my default account team to accounts that I create or accounts that are transferred to me"

Tags: account-teams

Is there a way to user dataloader to check this box for a large list of users?   I have checked all of these objects, but cannot find where this checkbox value is stored:  User, UserAccountTeamMember, UserEntityAccess.

Here is my use case:   We use Anaplan to assign Accounts to Sales Reps.  Anaplan will push the new OwnerID onto the Account, and then the Default Account Team members will automatically be added to this Account **IF** the checkbox is marked as true.
I can dataload default Account team members, but I they will not autoflow into new/transfered Accounts unless I have that checkbox true for all of the Sales Reps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's never been a way to check that box, other than manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've inspected the objects related to User and the only object I would think that could contain this settings is the [UserPreference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userpreference.htm). However, while having a user with the "Automatically add my default account team to accounts that I create or accounts that are transferred to me" setting enabled, the following query yields no helpful results:

```
SELECT Preference, Value, UserId FROM UserPreference
```

[image]

I tried listing out the fields on UserAccountTeamMember just to make sure the documentation is not missing a checkbox, but without a helpful result as well:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.UserAccountTeamMember.fields.getMap();
for(Schema.SObjectField field : fieldMap.values()){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
    String label = fieldResult.getLabel();
    System.debug('The field label is: ' + label);
}
```

[image]

It seems to be a manual work unless you want to create a custom checkbox and custom Apex logic to reference it.